# Python 3 - webbrowser module - open() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

i write a piece of code in python, im a beginner and im learning modules.

```
import webbrowser as ac
ac.open("istihza.com")
```

it works correctly but when i run that, site is opening in internet explorer.
i want to make it opened with google chrome. Is any parameter to change browser? or i need something else?

Comment: Make sure the Chome executable is on the path (%PATH% on Windows, $PATH on Linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply grab the appropriate controller instance and open the url with that:

```
import webbrowser as ac

chrome =ac.get('chrome')
chrome.open('istihza.com')
```